# How to open Yaml files in python from http?

Tags: python, http, yaml

I am currently learning python and as part of a challenge to myself I would like to be able to create a script that can automatically identify a book from it's barcode.

I already have an API key for isbndb.com, which can return requests in plain Yaml. I've already been able to read Yaml files locally from my harddrive and display information about the book, but I would like to be able to open these files directly from http.

I've already done some googling around but I couldn't find much on this topic.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Use the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library. There are complete examples at that link.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Open YAML files in Python from HTTP reads as if you want to serve them as static files from your http server and then have them open Python, or a specific python program to process the info. Is that correct (and does mean the part in your post about barcodes etc is irrelevant?)